# Cycle Through Background Colors of Table Rows on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This javascript toggles between two colors:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#rowClick").children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").click(function(){
    $(this.parentNode).toggleClass("enroute");
});
```

});

CSS:

```
.placed{
background: #3498db;}

.pickedUp{
background: #f1c40f;}

.enroute{
background: #2ecc71;}
```

I've found a couple great examples here: http://jsfiddle.net/pqyxM/5/ and http://jsfiddle.net/FSFpZ/

However, I want the color cycling to be triggered by clicks on a row in a specific column and I need the color change to be saved. Is this possible? Any comments are much appreciated.

Comment: where do you want to save the color? the server or local (cookie)?

Comment: This doesn't answer your questions but I'd suggest changing your code to $('#rowClick').on('click', 'td', function() { });  It creates less overhead with only 1 attached event and it also supports the ability to add more rows without having to recreate click events for the new rows.  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I'd like to save the color to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but with a bit of extra code you can toggle the class name and save it to a variable.

Then you can use this variable to toggle the next color: http://jsfiddle.net/reubenhutton/FSFpZ/55/

```
var className; 
    $.each(classes, function(key, val){
        if($(self).hasClass(val)){
            className = val;
            $(self).removeClass(val); 
        }
    })
```

Comment: Can you save the color var to the server? Also, could you link the color change to a click on a specific column in the row (vs anywhere on in the row)?

Comment: I am trying to save background color changes to server. Any clarification would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: If you want to save the changes made to the tr's, adding methods in the controller is an easier hack.